# Dynamically display values in dropdown box and then show the selected values as selected by the user which is already stored in the DB

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu

Dynamically display values in dropdown box and then show the selected values as 
selected by the user which is already stored in the DB.
**Below Code**

```
<form:select class="form-control required" name= "type_st" id="type_st">
  <form:option value="AA">Austerlia</form:option>
  <form:option value="BB">Bangladesh</form:option>
  <form:option value="BOTH">Both</form:option>
</form:select>
```

If user selected AA and saved as draft are submitted, when  again show that page it should show AA along with other two options

Comment: Could you please rephrase your question, as it is it is quite difficult to understand what you're asking for.

Comment: Simple I want to put "selected" in the drop down menu if the option value matched with database stored value.

Answer (score 0):

If you are already saving state in DB as you mention, transform that state to do is the attribute `selected` to your markup.
Example from MDN docs below,
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/select

```
`<!-- The second value will be selected initially -->
<select name="select"> <!--Supplement an id here instead of using 'name'-->
  <option value="value1">Value 1</option> 
  <option value="value2" selected>Value 2</option>
  <option value="value3">Value 3</option>
</select>`
```